# how to update jfree line chart in RCP View

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have four views in Eclipse RCP App. In that 3 View are responsible to show the multiline graphs. i am using a switch case for drawing the graph continuously until other views are get focused. But the view are not showing the updated chart.
The following is the case for update the graph. i have two datasets for sample updation of the view.

All the replies are appreciated.

case 1:

```
System.out.println("in Case "+selectedViewId);
while(selectedViewId==1){
    try {
        Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        while(count<20) {
            count++;
            System.err.println("Countttttttt "+count);
            if(count%2==0){
                System.err.println(".....Oneeeeeeee");
                IViewPart vp =  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView("RCP.CPU");
                PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().hideView(vp);
                PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().resetPerspective();
                try {
                    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("RCP.CPU");
                } catch (PartInitException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                int value = CPU.value=1;
                CPU cpuView = CPUSingleton.getCPUObject();
            }
            else {
                System.err.println(".....tWOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
                IViewPart vp =  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView("RCP.CPU");
                PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().hideView(vp);
                PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().resetPerspective();
                try {
                    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("RCP.CPU");
                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int value = CPU.value=2;
                CPU cpuView = CPUSingleton.getCPUObject();
            }
        }
        }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

break;
```